# Is there an easy way OR a workaround to display different looking image depending on the value of a variable in React?

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm creating a website for my company. I'm quite inexperimented, I'm working there as an intern.
I have to do a reporting on this website. One of the fields in 5 hearts displaying depending the value of a variable: if the variable's value is 2.5, hearts 1 & 2 will be filled with red, heart 3 will be half red half gray and the others will be gray.

I did some researches about how to manipulate images in React and css, and I found about filters, and especially the grayscale option. Sadly, I couldnt find a way to set it only for a part of the image.

The idea would be to have a method to be called in my component's render method like this :

```
displayHearts = content => {
    // content is a float, value between 0 and 5
    // depending on the content, the return would be different
    return (
        <div>
            <p>{content}</p>
            --> display of 5 hearts, gray or red depending on content
        </div>
    );
}
```

Here is a sample of what I would like it to look like:

https://ibb.co/VYBzXtQ

It is possible for me to install any modules to help me do that.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: you can use https://github.com/voronianski/react-star-rating-component package

Comment: Thank you for the help @Sumanth. I tested the package, it gets pretty close to what I would like to achieve, but it looks like it can't display say two third of an icon in case my rating is 2.6, or atleast I do not understand how to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of going about it is to render 5 grey hearts and 5 absolutely positioned red hearts above it, and use the `content` prop to figure out how much of the red hearts that should be visible.

**Example**

```
function HeartScoreIndicator({ content }) {
  return (
    <div style={{ display: "inline-block", position: "relative" }}>
      <div>
        {Array.from({ length: 5 }, (_, index) => (
          <img key={index} src="/images/grey-heart.png" />
        ))}
      </div>
      <div
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          width: `${content * 20}%`,
          whiteSpace: "nowrap",
          overflow: "hidden"
        }}
      >
        {Array.from({ length: 5 }, (_, index) => (
          <img key={index} src="/images/red-heart.png" />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Amazing! It works almost wonders. Two quick questions if you don't mind : is it possible, using your solution to:
- have the score displayed on the left side of the hearts;
- have the hearts resize depending on the size of the div calling the function?
Thanks a lot, it is already a huge improvement!

Comment: @Ragnar Great! That was not part of your question. Please don't change the question after it has been answered. If you feel my answer answered your original question [you can accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235) and if you can't figure out how to scale it, you can create a new question.

Comment: Understood, I will create a new one. Thanks again!