# How can I resize image array and text to best fit the parent container?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm creating a website for my company. I'm quite inexperimented, I'm working there as an intern. I have to do a reporting on this website. To do so, I have created "cards" that will each display a part of this reporting. Right now, I'm working on a "heart-like" score display. I have had great insight on how to do that in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55741861/is-there-an-easy-way-or-a-workaround-to-display-different-looking-image-dependin/55742537?noredirect=1#comment98163368_55742537). What I would like to do now is to have something that looks like that : https://ibb.co/VYBzXtQ
with the score displayed on the left of the hearts. The main issue I currently have is that I'd like the hearts to best fit the parent container.

As you might see in the jsfiddle, this is the architecture I'm using:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            //my hearts display
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried playing around with flexbox, to no avail.

To best describe what my issue is, I created a jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/dLr1v32y/5/

I'd like the score to be displayed on the left of the container, under the title. On its right, fitting all the space left, I'd like to have the 5 hearts. Note that I'm happy with the solution that was offered to me, I just would like the tweaks to make it fit best the container.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Made some modifications to your solution. Maybe this would help. https://jsfiddle.net/qckf0m1s/

Comment: Thanks for the update for the score. I added it to my project in a similar way. Now I just need a way to figure out how to scale those hearts to fit the parent